# How to make grub2 boot before os loads

Tags: linux, windows, bootloader, grub

I feel kinda silly asking this but I would like to know if it is possible to have grub2 boot before an OS loads. I'm currently running an ACER V3-571-6643 with windows 8 on it and I installed Ubuntu 12, using the grub2 boot loader to dual boot. The only issue I have is that when I start my laptop it loads Windows 8 before the grub2 menu shows creating a delay in boot time. If I want to boot Ubuntu I still have to wait for windows 8 to load to get to the grub 2 menu and then I can boot to Ubuntu which appears to restart the computer and then boot the os. Is there any way to have grub2 load and then choose an os to load? If not I'm sorry for wasting time.

The boot order for my laptop appears to be:

```
ACER start up screen
v
Windows boot logo (loading the OS)
v
Grub2
v
whatever OS is chosen
```

(when windows is chosen it goes to login instantly because it has already been loaded)

(when Ubuntu is chosen the computer restarts and loads Ubuntu and goes straight into login after loading the OS)

Comment: That's just the way Win8 loads I guess due to the hybrid boot option. You can try EasyBCD and see if adding both OSes to the NeoGrub menu helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the live flash or disk and install boot-repair with these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

It's better to take a look at this link : 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

and then use recommended repair and after that it's easy .

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help at all. The issue I described above is still occurring.